# TCP buffer sizes and ethernet bonding

Tags: tcp, linux-kernel

(This question was originally posted on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133568/tcp-buffer-sizes-and-ethernet-bonding); Andy told me that I could get faster help here, so it is re-posted here now.)

I am experimenting with TCP buffer size tuning on Linux, but various results make me confused.

The test programs include a server and a client.  The server simply listens on a port, waiting for the client to send data from an mmaped file.  The received data is copied into an application buffer using `recv` and then dropped.  While sending data, the client uses `send` with the full size of the mmapped buffer as the initial argument.

The programs run on two nodes from two different datacenters, the ping response time between them is about 9 msecs.  Both nodes are installed two Gigabit ethernet controllers.  The maximum throughput is 256 MB/s, and a proper setting of send/recv buffer sizes should be about 256 MB/s * 0.09 s ~ 2415919 bytes.

I did several experiments.

In the first run, I ran one instance of server and one instance of client.  I did not set the size of either the send buffer or the receive buffer, letting the kernel autotune them.  The purpose of this case is to establish a baseline of other experiments.

The actual throughput in this setting was about 117 MB/s.  A single pair of server and client made use of only one eithernet controller in this case.  Checking with `ifconfig`, I saw that most packets went through a single interface between `eth0` and `eth1`.

Then I tried two servers and two clients, this time the throughput moved up to about 225 MB/s, much nearer to the ideal maximum throughput.

This is the first issue confusing me:

1. Why do I need more than one process to use up the bandwidth?  FWIW, below is part of `/proc/net/bonding/bond0`:

   ```
   Bonding Mode: IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation
   Transmit Hash Policy: layer3+4 (1)
   MII Status: up
   MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
   Up Delay (ms): 0
   Down Delay (ms): 0
   ```

Then I tried several combinations of send/recv buffer sizes for a single pair of server and client.  The following table summarizes the results:

```
| send buf size | recv buf size | throughput | comment                   |
|      (client) |      (server) |     (MB/s) |                           |
|       1048576 |             - |       51.5 |                           |
|       2621400 |             - |       48.6 | server uses autotuning    |
|        524288 |             - |       43.3 |                           |
|       8388608 |             - |       36.3 |                           |
|       2621400 |       2621400 |       33.0 | somewhat the theory value |
|             - |       2621400 |       30.4 | client uses autotuning    |
|       4194304 |             - |       30.3 |                           |
|        262144 |             - |       29.1 |                           |
|             - |       1048576 |       27.9 |                           |
|       6291456 |       6291456 |       26.5 |                           |
|       8388608 |       8388608 |       23.9 |                           |
|       6291456 |             - |       22.2 |                           |
|             - |       4194304 |       20.8 |                           |
|       1048576 |       1048576 |       19.8 |                           |
|       4194304 |       4194304 |       19.3 |                           |
|             - |       8388608 |       19.3 |                           |
|             - |       6291456 |       13.8 |                           |
```

Here are several other questions raised up from the above table:

2. Why does the theory value not result in the best throughput (117 MB/s)?
3. Why is the best result (51.5 MB/s) still not as good as the result of kernel autotuning (117 MB/s)?
4. Why does bigger buffer result in poor throughput?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: During the re-posting, I got the idea that question 2 might be related to question 1.  As a single process can only use up a single ethernet controller, the theory value of buffer size should be computed with 1Gb instead of 2Gb, resulting in about 1MB buffers.

Comment: There's no relations between processes and ethernet interfaces. Each socket is bound to a single interface, explicitly by `bind` or implicitly e.g. by `connect`. It's possible to use both interfaces from the same process, you just need to bind 2 sockets to different interfaces. By default, binding implicitly or specifying `0` as an IP address, you bind to the default (the first) interface.